# Find the area of the triangle $AEZ$ in the figure

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: The angle measure $\angle ERZ=75^o$ and $EH=6$. Calculate the area of ​​the triangular region $ZEA$.(Answer:S=4)

[image]

My progress:

$OA =R\\
\triangle OAZ(equilateral)\implies S\triangle OAZ = \frac{R^2\sqrt3}{4}\\
S_{OAEZ} = \frac{\pi R^2}{6}$

S(segment AEZ) = $\frac{\pi R^2}{6} - \frac{R^2\sqrt3}{4}$

????

Comment: The area of the quadrilateral $OAEZ$ is not equal to $\frac{πR^2}{6}$.

Comment: Can you please provide a more precise statement of the problem? It seems like we have a semicircle with diameter $AR,$ where $R$ lies on $AE,$ and $H$ is a point on the semicircle. However, the location of the center of this semicircle is ambiguous. Is the answer independent of it?

Comment: @ErenKesim I considered OAEZ is a circular sector. For those who already know me on the forum, the problems I post are copies identical to the original. Therefore, it is up to the interpretation of each one to try to solve

Comment: Then, the area of $\triangle{AEZ}$ is not equal to the difference between the area of that circular sector and the area of $\triangle{OAZ}$

Comment: @ErenKesim You are correct, it would be the area of ​​the segment to circle $AEZ$

Comment: I believe, answer is 9 not 4.

Comment: @Ivan Kaznacheyeu it's possible...it could be an error in the template.. There is an alternative that indicates 9 as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let consider what we see in the drawing. Center of arc AHR is located in edge AR, then AR is diameter. Then triangle AHR is rectangular and EH is altitude of rectangular triangle dropped on hypotenuse. Then $$EH^2=AE\cdot ER$$

Angle AEZ is inscribed angle with corresponding arc A(not E)Z, which angular measure is $360^\circ-60^\circ=300^\circ$. Then AEZ$=150^\circ$.

In triangle REZ angle REZ$=30^\circ$, angle ERZ$=75^\circ$, then angle $EZR=75^\circ$. Then REZ is isosceles triangle with ER=EZ.

Area of triangle AEZ is $$S=\frac12 AE \cdot EZ \cdot \sin(150^\circ)=\frac14 AE\cdot EZ=\frac14 AE\cdot ER=\frac14 EH^2=9$$

Comment: excellent...thankful